# scipy interp1d extrapolation method fill_value = tuple not working

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I want to extrapolate a function fit.
scipy.interpolate.interp1d is supposed to be able to do this (see doc snippet).
Instead I get "ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range."

Using: python 2.7.12, numpy 1.13.3, scipy 0.19.1

> fill_value : array-like or (array-like, array_like) or "extrapolate", optional
>      - if a ndarray (or float), this value will be used to fill in for
>        requested points outside of the data range. If not provided, then
>        the default is NaN. The array-like must broadcast properly to the
>        dimensions of the non-interpolation axes.
>      - If a two-element tuple, then the first element is used as a
>        fill value for `x_new < x[0]` and the second element is used for
>        `x_new > x[-1]`. Anything that is not a 2-element tuple (e.g.,
>        list or ndarray, regardless of shape) is taken to be a single
>        array-like argument meant to be used for both bounds as
>        `below, above = fill_value, fill_value`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
# make a time series
nobs = 10
t = np.sort(np.random.random(nobs))
x = np.random.random(nobs)
# compute linear interp (with ability to extrapolate too)
f1 = interp1d(t, x, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate') # this works
f2 = interp1d(t, x, kind='linear', fill_value=(0.5, 0.6)) # this doesn't
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d), `interp1d` defaults to raising `ValueError` on extrapolation except when `fill_value='extrapolate'` or when you specify `bounds_error=False`.

```
In [1]: f1 = interp1d(t, x, kind='linear', fill_value=(0.5, 0.6), bounds_error=False)

In [2]: f1(0)
Out[2]: array(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, Craig. I assumed that supplying a tuple value to fill_value would cause it to be used (maybe unless you also explicitly set bounds_error=False for some reason). Apparently this not the behavior of interp1d.